# cant create a form instance in another class file of the same project in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I have created a new form in the existing class library project. The form uses the same name space. I have a existing class file. I can not create the instance of the new form.

```
Form1 frm=new Form1();
```

The above code is not working in the existing class, but If I add a new class then It is working fine.

I need to access the form in the existing class. Please help me to access this form.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Where is **()**: `Form1 frm = new Form1();`

Comment: I did not write in the question"()", but in code I have written. Intellisense is also not showing Form1.

Comment: Can you describe what error are you getting?

Comment: We can't replicate this issue with the code you've shown. You need to show all of the relevant code to get any help. Otherwise this question should be deleted.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: the type or namespace name 'Form1' could not be found (are you missing a assembly or reference)

Answer (score 0):

As @reza-aghaei already pointed out, your error might be the fact that you forgot to add () to the end if your statement:

`Form1 frm=new Form1();`

Answer (score 0):

Usually Visual Studio is smart enough to suggest what could be Wrong - perhaps its ReSharper that tells about mismatch in visibility of types in different parts of projects or other projects - as in your case the form is in a class library.

Just check that your form is not internal to the class library. you would see it on the Form1 class definition. if it is internal or private make it public.

if for some reason you can not make it public atleast make it visible to the consuming assembly using the InternalsVisibleToAttribute Class : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Guys.

I have added the reference in the class library again as

```
using "Project folder Name";
```

This potential fix is shown by VS2015 Intellisense.

This is strange behavior of code, as the code is working fine in the new classes with out adding the any reference. But in the existing class it working after adding the reference only.

Thank you every one.

Comment: Did you try `Ctrl + .` or hovering mouse over the word with error?

Comment: Yes, On mouse hover it was showing this fix. and added the my folder name as shown in the picture. Now it is working fine. Thank you.